# How to put to text beside a span or image?

Tags: html, css

Hi guys how can it put the text beside the orange circle

i tried using " float : left " but the text would get out of the white bock

i also used display: inline-block
and its not working.

![i want the text in the yellow region and nothing exceed the the red live

also to fix small pictures for buttons in the blue region][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLhCi.png)

you can check out the work [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/6cq5zbo3/)

html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="row text-right">


            <div class="col-xsm-6">
                <div class="panel mini-box">
                    <div > <span class="btn-icon btn-icon-round btn-icon-lg-alt bg-danger">
                            <span class="ti-stats-up">1</span>
</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-info" >
                        <p class="step" >جلب المستمسكات الا اربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكات الاربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكات الاربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكات اربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكات الاربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكات الاربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكاتربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكات الاربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكات الاربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكات الاربعة مع استنساخ ملون<span class="size-h4"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for such cases you may use http://www.bootply.com/ - looks like jsfiddle but has an bootstrap already

Comment: I don't get it, you pasted 11874 lines of CSS... On top of that you used inline styles... the circles positions are (at least from a designer's perspective) all off... You cannot expect that one will run all over your entire styles. Try to exclude from the styles anything that is not related to your issue (or put the Bootstrap's CSS in an external link). Don't use inline styles (that's why you have a *stylesheet*).  Also `<DIV>orange circle</DIV><DIV><p  style="float:right">text</p></DIV>` notice that p is inside a DIV?

Comment: thanks guys ill do the changes and see how can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using multiple div blocks, you could put your text in a simple `span` besides your orange circle `span` like this :

```
[...]
<div class="panel mini-box">
    <div style="margin-left: 5px">
         <span class="btn-icon btn-icon-round btn-icon-lg-alt bg-danger">
             <span class="ti-stats-up">1</span>
         </span>
         <span class="box-info">جلب المستمسكات الا اربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكات الاربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكات الاربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكات اربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكات الاربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكات الاربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكاتربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكات الاربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكات الاربعة مع استنساخ ملون جلب المستمسكات الاربعة مع استنساخ ملون</span>
    </div>
</div>
[...]
```

Be sure to remove the `display:inline-block;` on your `.box-info` element. I tried in your JSfiddle and it worked.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume :) i'm very thankful to you :) its working .

how can i maintain the area below the orange circle white that means i remains in an transparent box beside the circle ? 

if this could happen it would be great :) 

you can check the picture 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/xLhCi.png

Comment: maybe you could try to add a margin to your orange circle, like `margin:10px;`